# I have a NullPointerException in a mock, and I don't know what to do

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

i'm doing a mock for this method:

```
public String buscarDescripcion(MaestroDTO departamento, String codigoMunicipio){
        String descripcion = null;
        List<MaestroDTO> listaMunicipios = getListaMucipios(departamento);
        if(listaMunicipios != null) {
            for (MaestroDTO maestroDTO : listaMunicipios) {
                if(maestroDTO.getCodigo().equals(codigoMunicipio)){
                    descripcion = maestroDTO.getNombre();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return descripcion;
    }
```

In a Test class. This return a list full of names of cities.
But when I run the test, I have the NullPointerException error.
The mock that I'm using in the test class is this:

```
listaCiudad = mock(ListaCiudad.class);

when(listaCiudad.buscarDescripcion(any(MaestroDTO.class), any(BigDecimal.class).toString())).thenReturn("MEDELLIN");
```

The method buscarDescripcion have two parameters, MaestroDTO and one String. When I run the test using a String, this show me an cast error. And when I'm using a BigDecimal.toString() this show me a nullpointerexception. I don't know if I'm calling in a wrong way this parameters, because I don't know too much about mocks!
I appreciate your help! Thank you! (sorry for my english).

Comment: Syntax `when(object.methodCall()).thenReturn(x)` executes the real method anyway. If you want to avoid it, use `doReturn(x).when(object).methodCall())` instead.

Comment: The stack trace or debugger ought to tell you what's null.  I'm guessing it's something else that your mock isn't dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You are not stubbing your mock correctly. You should replace `any(BigDecimal.class).toString()` with `MockitoanyString()`

```
Mockito.when(listaCiudad.buscarDescripcion(Mockito.any(MaestroDTO.class), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("MEDELLIN");
```

Comment: you mean *stubbing* :)

Comment: It says The method anyString() is undefined for the type ExtractorIncapacidadesTest.. (the name of the test class)

Comment: @KarenTatianaGmezSuarez-Ce `Mockito.anyString()`. This is equivalent to `Mockito.any(String.class)`

Comment: @noscreenname I think it works, thank you so much. Saludos!